# How to set the Swiper.js speed (transition duration) to zero on mouse Enter?

Tags: javascript, css, swiper.js

I made a slider with Swiper.js which automatically scrolls in a loop.

My code: https://codepen.io/BehnamAzg/pen/NWzmBKo

I wanted it to stop scrolling when it's being hovered, so I add this code:

```
autoplay: {
    disableOnInteraction: false,
    pauseOnMouseEnter: true
  }
```

This is working fine, but the speed of scrolling is too high
so to adjust that I have to add a **speed** (transition duration) to it. but by adding this it makes the mouseEnter a **delay** to make an effect.

For example:
If I set the "speed" to 5000ms, it would take 5 seconds till the slider stops scrolling when it's hovered.

I don't want this "speed attribute" effects my hovering, I want it to immediately stop the scrolling.

For solving this, I tried to add a **delay** instead of speed but it will remove the smoothness of scrolling.

I tried to set the transition duration to zero while being hovered with CSS, but that also didn't work:

```
.swiper:hover > .swiper-wrapper {
  transition-duration: 0 !important;
}
```

I also tried to add a swiper.setProgress(progress, speed) to it and set the speed to zero, it did work but it will mess up the progress of the slider:

```
$(".swiper").each(function(elem, target){
  var test = target.swiper;
  $(this).hover(function() {
      test.setProgress(0, 0);
  }, function() {
      test.setProgress(0, 5000);
  });
});
```

I don't know what to do anymore, any suggestions?!